# Visual Studio MFC Cstring format

Tags: c++, mfc

I am developing an MFC Interface with Visual Studio, but the output is not as it should. I am using the same code as the on used in codeblocks but the output here is different and i think it's because of the format. What is the correct way to enter 'e' and 'd' in my 'IDC_Values' ? I searched online but couldn't find much about MFC

```
int e[100], d[100];

CString Text;
Text.Format((LPCWSTR)L"%d \t%d", e, d);
SetDlgItemText(IDC_Values, Text);
```

Comment: `e` and `d` are arrays, so printing them with the `%d` format specifier is wrong. What are you trying to achieve? Print the 1st element of the arrays? Print all elements of the arrays? Also you don't needd the `(LPCWSTR)` cast before the format string. What is `IDC_Values`? The id of an edit control, of a static or...? Show an example of values in `e`and in `d` and the text you want to put in `IDC_Values` (what ever control `IDC_Values` is).

Comment: I want to print all elements of the array

Comment: IDC_Values is the id of an edit control

Comment: As to the `LPCWSTR` cast -- **never** cast string types, even though it may "work".  If a string can't live by itself without casts being applied, the code could and should be considered wrong.  Casting is a sign that you're trying to shut the compiler up about an error about differing string types.  Instead, use the right type of string for the job.

Comment: You need to write a loop to print all values of the array.  Even so, how would `Format` know how to format a series of numbers?  A space in-between them?  Two spaces?  Carriage return?  A pipe symbol?

Comment: _I want to print all elements of the array_ that will put 200 values into the edit control. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CString is CStringW on UNICODE builds and CStringA on non UNICODE builds. So you should not mix wide literals with non wide, for example you have:

```
Text.Format((LPCWSTR)L"%d \t%d", e, d);
                     ^ ~~~~ this requires that CString is wide
```

this should be (minus the fact that e and d are arrays!!):

```
Text.Format(_T("%d \t%d"), e, d);
```

Now if you want to format a string, and set it to widget, then you must iterate it (warning: I have not compiled this code):

```
CString Text;
CString tmp;
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(e)/sizeof(e[0]); ++i) {
  tmp.Format(_T("%d,"), e[i]);
  Text += tmp;
}

// here the same for d
```

I am not saying its the most efficent way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the content of an array you must iterate the array and build the string
I guess you want a list having rows and columns containg e[] and d[]?
I assume that e. d are filled completely.
If so you need to code
like

```
int e[100], d[100];
CString Text;
CString Line
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    Line.Format((LPCWSTR)L"%d \t%d\r\n", e, d);
    Text+=Line;
}
SetDlgItemText(IDC_Values, Text);
```

This will generate a multiline string containing the values of e and d.
If this is what you want.